# Text is hidden under floating nav menu when clicking a hashtag hyperlink

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a floating horizontal nav menu for a glossary page. When I click on a hashtag hyperlink to take me to another definition on the page, the `<dt>` part is hidden underneath the nav menu.

Is it possible to make sure the text is displayed below the floating nav menu?

Please see my sketched up [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MmDyn/) and click the yellow highlighted hyperlink.

Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: does it have to be floated? if you fix its position like the nav atop it, you won't have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solution from @Brandon I targeted the anchors:

```
div > a, dt > a {
padding-top: 22px;
margin-top: -22px;
}
```

This did not require any additional markup.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of javascript or deprecated framesets you could do something like this:

```
<dt class="highlight" id='ccdcd'><div class='jump-to-able'></div>ccdcd</dt>

.jump-to-able {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bQ4kH/1/

Comment: I replaced the empty anchor with an empty div, really the more elegant solution would be to use javascript so there aren't unnecessary elements muddying up the markup.

Comment: You'll need to set overflow: hidden; on DT as well.

Comment: Thanks for that, we're getting closer. Based on your solution, I tried adding an empty div to my original markup and that in itself seems to fix it. However, how can I get the `<dt>` to have the same properties as the `<div>` as I do not want additional markup. I tried `dt {display: block}` but it didn't work. Please see my update: (http://jsfiddle.net/MmDyn/1/)

Comment: Hmmm...it appears that block level elements should not be nested within a `<dt>`.

Comment: I was able to use your CSS `{padding-top: 20px;margin-top: -20px;}` on the anchors. This meant I didn't have to add any markup. Thanks for your help.